# User.IsInRole always returns false in View or code using Policy based Authorization

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm working on an Asp.net Core MVC app with windows authentication. I defined a policy based authorization role in startup.cs using the code below.

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
     options.AddPolicy("Main", policy => policy.RequireRole(Configuration["APP:ADGroup"]));
});
```

This works fine as long as I use Authorize attribute on a Controller method but if I try to use `User.IsInRole("Main")` in code then it fails and always returns false whether in code or view.

I essentially want to write a simple if statement in view that shows a link depending on user's role. E.g.

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Main"))
{
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome Main</h1>
}
else
{
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome Others</h1>
}
```

It always returns Others...

If I use

```
@if(User.IsInRole("AdGroupname"))
     do something
```

then it works.

I guess the question is how do I get it to work with just the policy name instead of the entire AD group name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this MS docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/views?view=aspnetcore-5.0). It describes policy based authorization using `IAuthorizationService`.

```cs
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@inject IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService

@if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "PolicyName")).Succeeded)
{
    <p>This paragraph is displayed because you fulfilled PolicyName.</p>
}
```

Note the warning at the bottom of the docs page about using this method

> Warning
>
> Don't rely on toggling visibility of your app's UI elements as the
> sole authorization check. Hiding a UI element may not completely
> prevent access to its associated controller action. For example,
> consider the button in the preceding code snippet. A user can invoke
> the Edit action method if he or she knows the relative resource URL is
> /Document/Edit/1. For this reason, the Edit action method should
> perform its own authorization check.